# Prove that In A simple linear regression, $SSR/\sigma^2$ follows chi square with one degree of freedom

Tags: regression

In A simple linear regression, $SSR/\sigma^2$ follows chi square with one degree of freedom where SSR denotes the sum of squares due to regression.

Although I get that it will have one degree of freedom, I just am not able to think how to prove that  $SSR/\sigma^2$ will follow chi square. How do I prove that it's the square of a standard normal?. I am new to statistics and self learning.
I tried searching the site. But most of the answers are given in the context of multi linear regression. I don't understand multi linear much right now . I just need a hint in proving that it can be expressed as the square of a standard normal...

Could someone please help. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+chi+square+degree+freedom).

Comment: @whuber I tried searching. But most of the answers are given in the context of multi linear regression. I don't understand multi linear much right now

Comment: OK, I found more answers by searching "anova degrees freedom."  Some interesting related posts can be found by searching for "cochran's theorem."

Comment: @whuber I'm sorry but I understand the degree of freedom part. I just need help in proving that it follows chi square in a simple linear regression. Could you please guide me. I have been stuck for long

Comment: That it must be a multiple of a chi-squared distribution follows from expressing it as the square of a Normally distributed variable.  You can search for many explanations of this by including "normal chi squared distribution" in your search.

Comment: @whuber will the chi square feature be also be proved using Cochran theorem?

Comment: Cochran's Theorem shows how to express SSR as the square of a variable.  The rest requires only knowing that the chi-squared distribution is *defined* as being that of the square of a standard Normal variable.

Comment: @whuber aah I see. So, I will have to know Cochran's theorem to be able to see that it can be expressed as the square of a standard normal....

Comment: @whuber the theorem involves a lot of matrix theory. Do you think a simpler proof is possible in the case of simple linear regression?